# Only accept numbers as GET-variable

Tags: php, get

Hello,

I want to allow only numbers in `$_GET` method. I use this is in pagination to secure

`$page = (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1);`

If I enter special characters or alpha, it returns error

This should not be possible:

`index.php?page=AA` and 
`index.php?page='!@#$%^&*()`

Only this:
`index.php?page=1` or `2 ...`

Anyone has a solution for this? :) thanks in advance...

Comment: SO what is the problem? You line of php seems to check for the value to exist and if it is nummeric. What doens't work for you?

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: as what iv'e post this is on pagination 

`$offset = 3;
$limit = ($page - 1) * $offset;
$onset = $limit + $offset;`

if i put zero on parameter it will return error also to alpa and special characters...

Comment: Can you post your whole code. Is the error contain something like "division by 0"?

Comment: @HannibalBurr I guess you could add `&& (int)$page > 0` to the if statement to avoid zero and negative numbers.

Comment: here http://pastebin.com/Pe78ED3z

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest the use of [`filter_input()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

```
$page= filter_input ( INPUT_GET, 
                      'page', 
                      FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                      array('options'=>array('min_range' => 1)));
if(!$page)$page=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use [`intval()`](http://www.php.net/intval) and a default value for `$page`:

```
$page = 1;

if ( isset($_GET['page']) )
  $page = intval($_GET['page']);
```

Comment: Is there a page 0. Isn't the first page most of the time `1`?

Comment: I've just changed it to 1 ;) I thought he directly puts this variable into the MySQL query: `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT $page, 10`. But he calculates the limit with: `$limit = ($page - 1) * $offset;`

Comment: the calculation is good but, only in alpa and special chars... whew.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to number using `intval` then check it. If the value is not numeric, `intval` will return 0:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
    if (intval($_GET['page'] == 0)
        $page = 1;
    else
        $page = intval($_GET['page']);
```

or more compact:

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) && intval($_GET['page'] != 0) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
```

Comment: it's good bro, but when i put alpa and special chars on parameter returns Object not found!

Answer (score 0):

You've got a closing bracket in the wrong place - it should be:

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
```

Comment: Note the second closing bracket after `is_numeric()`